# Add Items to a Listview in another form via a method in the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I am trying to pass some values to a method in another form and this method works for adding some values into a listView in this form. It seems working, because there is no error message. Can someone help me where did I make wrong? Thanks for replies!

My code is looks like:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }     

  public void AddToTaskMan(string tarih, string gorevturu, string barkod, string actiondate, string actionid, string actionreasonid, string courieragentname, 
            string courieragentcode, string courierregionname, string courierregioncode, string courierstaffname, string courierstaffcode, string tarih1, string tarih2)
        {

            try
            {
                Int32 i = listView1.Items.Count;
                listView1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(tarih);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(gorevturu);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(barkod);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(actiondate);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(actionid.ToString());
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(actionreasonid);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(courieragentname);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(courieragentcode);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(courierregionname);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(courierregioncode);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(courierstaffname);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(courierstaffcode);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(tarih1);
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(tarih2);


            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }


public partial class frmAddTask : Form
    {
        public frmAddTask()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string gorevturu;

            DateTime datetime_ = new DateTime();
            datetime_ = DateTime.Now;


            frmMain main = new frmMain();

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                gorevturu = "1";

                main.AddToTaskMan(Convert.ToString(datetime_), gorevturu, "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", txtDate1.ToString(), txtDate2.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                gorevturu = "2";
                main.AddToTaskMan(Convert.ToString(datetime_), gorevturu, txtBarcode.ToString(), txtActionDate.ToString(), txtActionID.ToString(), txtReasonID.ToString(), txtCourierAgentName.ToString(), txtCourierAgentCode.ToString(), txtRegionName.ToString(), txtRegionCode.ToString(), txtStaffName.ToString(), txtStaffCode.ToString(), "-", "-");
            }


        }
```

Comment: in frmMain, method "AddToTaskMan" used try-catch block and the exception caught is being swallowed - can you remove the try-catch and let the error throw out, and you may fix it by your own when you know the cause!

Comment: What is the problem here `catch{}` is really a badpractice

Comment: Actually, In my original code there are some codes written. But I removed while I am passing my code to here to not show a code salad. That means, It doesnt throw any error with or without try catch block.